# my variable is being given the value null and i don't see why

Tags: javascript

here is the code, in the console it is telling me that button is null.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type=button id="button">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript test.js

```
function showAlert(){
    alert("this is an alert");
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", showAlert);
```

Comment: Put it all in an onLoad handler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test.js` is being included before the `<button>` element. So, when the script is being executed, the element isn't there. So include your `<script>` *after* the element which you're accessing in it is declared.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button type=button id="button">Click me</button>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```